# How to 'require' a database schema in nodejs

Tags: node.js, model, mongoose, require

What is the best way to `require` a mongoose `Schema` in nodejs?

Originally I had these inside the app.js file but that is getting a bit large and unwieldy with more models.

Now I want to move them into a `models` folder and use `Model = require('./models/model')` to import them into app.js

How do I get it such that `Model` is populated with the actual model?

(`exports = mongoose.model(...)` fails and gives me a blank object; `exports.model = mongoose.model(...)` requires me to do Model.model to access it -- neither of these are the desired behavior)

===

Edit1

So basically I have taken

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema, ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  first_name: String,
  last_name: String,
  email: String
});
User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

and put it into `./models/user.js`

How do I get it such that its the equivalent of having this in the app.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app.js server file, include the model.js file like this:

```
var Model = require('./models/model');  //whatever you want to call it
```

You can then instantiate it in your server file like this:

```
//Initiate the  Business API endpoints
var model = new Model(mq, siteConf);
model.getUser(id, function() {
    // handle result
});
```

### ----

Then in your file you place in `models` folder named model.js (or whatever you want) you can set it up like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 

//MongoDB schemas
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var User = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  first_name: String,
  last_name: String,
  email: String
});
var UserModel = mongoose.model('User', User);

// your other objects defined ...


module.exports = function(mq, siteConf) {
//MongoDB
mongoose.connect(siteConf.mongoDbUrl);


// ------------------------
// READ API
// ------------------------

// Returns a user by ID
function getUser(id, found) {
    console.log("find user by id: " + id);
    UserModel.findById(id, found);
}

// Returns one user matching the given criteria
// mainly used to match against email/login during login
function getUserByCriteria(criteria, found) {
    console.log("find user by criteria: " + JSON.stringify(criteria));
    UserModel.findOne(criteria, found);
}



    // more functions for your app ...



return {
    'getUser': getUser, 
            'getUserByCriteria': getUserByCriteria
   };
};
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this solves my problem. Right now I am not even using methods on my models yet (really simple database ops using the value I get back from `mongoose.model`; things like `User.find()`)

Comment: *edited question to be a little more specific about what I'm trying to do. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: Edited answer more towards your question and eliminated the other tips for less confusion.  What you wanted was a cleaner app.js file so I propose you create a new file and place in /lib/ directory and include the file in app.js.  Then instantiate the Class and call its functions as shown.

Comment: You'll see I `return` the functions for the class and I create functions as wrappers for the functions you mentioned but call them too like UserModel.find(..) but I just named the var different at the top.  Using `found` is just a callback function so my code remains Asynchronous which is what you want to do with Node.js so your apps are non-blocking.

Comment: I see. So in order to async the db calls, each call has to be wrapped in its own function?

Comment: then in your exports function you return the functions like I did below.  I also just renamed the includes at top to match your attempts for clarity.  you may name your schema objects differently and call only `find` where I called `findById` but same thing you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok sure. This looks like a good point to start from. Thanks :)

Comment: and when i declare exports, I'm passing in handles to a config file and my message queue (mq) but you don't need to do that.  my config file has the url to mongoose and I log some requests to message bus thus my use of those.  don't be confused by those and you can omit those args if you like, or do something similar.